# How to handle update request from different users on same product collection for same productId on same time mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb-query

I am having product Collection. And i want to handle the case where 8 users checkout for same product at same time. And suppose all 8 users request went inside update part then at that time which user will get product and what about the update query of rest 7 users?

8 user inside same update function
one user get update and available product count 0
if product is not available sent error or rollback database

Answer (score 0):

You could implement a "lock" mechanism allow only one transaction on a given product at a time.

Maybe something like this. (I haven't tested this code; just sketching out the idea.)

```js
// utility function that just waits the specified duration and resolves
const sleep = duration => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, duration));

// a map of the currently active locks
const locks = {};

// productId: the key to lock on
// transaction: an async function that performs the transaction
// timeout: how long to keep retrying before throwing
async function withLock (productId, transaction, timeout) {

  // if there's already a lock on this id...
  if (locks[productId]) {

    // …and we've exhausted the timeout…
    if (timeout <= 0) {
      // …throw an error
      throw new Error('Unable to acquire lock');
    }

    // otherwise wait 100ms…
    await sleep(100);

    // …and try again, reducing the timeout
    return withLock(productId, transaction, timeout - 100);
  }

  // no existing lock on this productId; proceed.
  try {
    // establish the lock so other calls on this id have to wait
    locks[productId] = true;

    // perform the transaction
    return await transaction();
  }
  finally {
    // and release the lock
    delete locks[productId];
  }
}
```

With this in place you can then do:

```js
try {
  const result = await withLock(productId, async () => {
    // perform checkout, update mongo, deduct inventory, whatever
  }, 2000);
}
catch (e) {
  // something went wrong, possibly a lock timeout
}
```

And

Comment: Is there any mongoDb lock collection or any other way to slove. Rather then setTimeout because i dont want to hold the api for that much time

Comment: setTimeout isn't going to hold up the api. setTimeout is going to try again in 100ms if there's already a lock, and it will keep trying for 2 seconds before giving up. But there's nothing here that's holding up the API. There are probably off-the-shelf implementations of this kind of thing. I don't know, haven't looked, but it seems likely.

Comment: Thanks. Is there any other standard format to solve the same

Comment: Standard format to do the same thing as this example?